Gifting money to fathers brother in the UK
My uncle (fathers brother) is in the UK. I  want to give him money as a gift. Is there any provision (rules) I need to follow, or can I gift money to my uncle's daughter?

The uncle is in the UK, but where are you?

Also, what is your citizenship, and status in the country of your residence (citizen, immigrant, student, work-permit holder etc)?
